# Floating modal window with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to make a simple modal window like in this example http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ to float when the body of the page scrolls down and up on a specific location. It can be top right, bottom right or middle right.

I have used his code:

> ```
>  $(function () {
>
>      $("#dialog").dialog({
>          maxHeight: 200,
>          width: 400,
>          autoOpen: true,
>          show: {
>              effect: "blind",
>              duration: 1000
>          },
>          hide: {
>              effect: "explode",
>              duration: 1000
>          }
>      });
>      $("#opener").click(function () {
>          $("#dialog").dialog("open");
>      });
>
>      $(window).scroll(function () {
>
>          //after window scroll fire it will add define pixel added to that element.
>          set = $(document).scrollTop() + "px";
>
>          //this is the jQuery animate function to fixed the div position after scrolling.
>          $('#dialog').animate({ top: set }, { duration: 1000, queue: false });
>
>
>      });
>  });
> ```

how ever this will only float the text inside of the dialog not the whole window.

Any help would highly be appreciated :)

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle and put the code.

Comment: I tried but did not work... html code is same as in http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Where is your `position:absolute` css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the **"#dialog"** selector to **".ui-dialog"**,

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

     //after window scroll fire it will add define pixel added to that element.
     set = $(document).scrollTop() + "px";

     //this is the jQuery animate function to fixed the div position after scrolling.
     $('.ui-dialog').animate({ top: set }, { duration: 1000, queue: false });
 });
```

Because **$('#dialog')** converts into a new DOM element once the dialog box is created by jQuery UI, and the new DOM element can be identified via **$('.ui-dialog')**

Comment: This is correct. Sidenote: Man, with the duration at 1000, that is going to be one ugly transition. Oh, and it doesn't convert into a new DOM element, if that were the case events would have to be rebound causing a performance degradation, instead `.wrap()` is called.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I did not quiet understand your concern because I am not an expert on jquery. Can you please explain in detail? or show me the code that I am supposed to use?